# How to build customer added *.bb files on Yocto project?

Tags: build, yocto

I'm a beginner of Yocto project.
So, I'm really hope to know how to build *.bb files which I added.
I am added a *.bb file (dlt-daemon) to meta-*/meta-*/recipes-expends/dlt-daemon/dlt-daemon_v2.14.1.bb.
However, whenever I try to build it (bitbake core-image-weston) it isn't built.

I tried to build a *.bb file only ( bitbake -b ******/*.bb -c compile ) but there is no output file in the rootfs. ( I found the output files at build/tmp/work/arch****/dlt-daemon/2.14.1-r0/build/***** )

I'm not sure why it doesn't work?
Please, can I know how to build *.bb files which I added?

Comment: Do you have a custom layer and did you include it in `bblayers.conf`?

Comment: I do not my own layer.
I just added my bb file to existed layer.
Also, I use existing layer.conf file.
BBFILES += "${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bb \
    ${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bbappend"
is show the path of bb file, and my bb file is in this path.

Comment: But do you have a custom layer or did you put your recipe into an existing layer?

Comment: The thing what I want is that below.
1. I build original Yocto Project.
2. I add *.bb files in the meta-*/~/recipes-*/*/*.bb.
3. Build yocto project again. ( Not Clean build )
4. the bb files what I added at no.2 is built.
5. I can find the output files in the rootfs which is in build/tmp/deploy/images/*/*.tar.bz

I hope to follow this for build my bb files.

Comment: Which "meta-"? A custom one or an existing one? (meta-* ==> yocto layer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preferably, you should add your own recipes in your own layer.

But nevertheless, just adding a recipe (ie .bb-file) won't add it to any rootfs. If you can run

```
bitbake your-recipe
```

without getting any errors, your recipe is working as it should (there could still be some issues if you're not installing any files etc). You can confirm that it's working by either looking at the logs for the different tasks (in `${WORKDIR}/<arch>/recipe-name/recipe-version/temp/`).

Still being able to build your recipe isn't enough for what you want. For the application in question to appear in you rootfs, you need to add it to your image. Temporarily, you can add the following line to your `conf/local.conf`:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " <package-name>"
```

Note the leading space. To make it permanent, you should add the `<package-name>` to `IMAGE_INSTALL` directly in you image recipe.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I couldn't find the reason of my problem, but I succeed to build my own bb file by adding new layer.

Answer (score 0):

Open your local.conf file and add below line e.g: `hello.bb`

`IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " hello"`     # "space" before hello. this will add to your rfs image

Then compile your rfs using `bitbake core-image-minimal`